# Problema com Fast Colored TextBox (indentação)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Estou modificando um projeto de código aberto criado por Pavel Torgashov, chamado Fast Colored TextBox, e estou tendo problemas com a linguagem **VB** no editor, pois **os métodos e propriedades são indentados dentro das Interfaces**...

> Invés de ela ficar assim:

[image: Invés de ficar assim]

> Está assim:

[image: erro]

E o resto do código dentro dessa FCTB fica indentado para frente. **Aqui está o código original do parágrafo VB (Em C#)** (Extraído da classe `SyntaxHighlighter`):

```
    protected void VBAutoIndentNeeded(object sender, AutoIndentEventArgs args)
    {
        //end of block
        if (Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, @"^\s*(End|EndIf|Next|Loop)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            args.Shift = -args.TabLength;
            args.ShiftNextLines = -args.TabLength;
            return;
        }
        //start of declaration
        if (Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText,
                          @"\b(Class|Property|Enum|Structure|Sub|Function|Namespace|Interface|Get)\b|(Set\s*\()",
                          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            args.ShiftNextLines = args.TabLength;
            return;
        }
        // then ...
        if (Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, @"\b(Then)\s*\S+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            return;
        //start of operator block
        if (Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, @"^\s*(If|While|For|Do|Try|With|Using|Select)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            args.ShiftNextLines = args.TabLength;
            return;
        }

        //Statements else, elseif, case etc
        if (Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, @"^\s*(Else|ElseIf|Case|Catch|Finally)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            args.Shift = -args.TabLength;
            return;
        }

        //Char _
        if (args.PrevLineText.TrimEnd().EndsWith("_"))
        {
            args.Shift = args.TabLength;
            return;
        }
    }
```

OK, então daí eu converti o código para VB, e agora no meu projeto se encontra desse jeito:

```
    'end of block
  If Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, "(^\s*)End (Sub|Function|Property|Set|Class|Enum|Module|Structure|Namespace|Interface|Get)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     args.Shift = -args.TabLength
     args.ShiftNextLines = -args.TabLength
     Return
  ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, ".*(:|: |: )(End (If|While|Try|With|Using|SyncLock|Select)|EndIf|Next|Loop)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     args.ShiftNextLines = -args.TabLength
     Return
  End If
  'start of declaration
  If Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, $"(^\s*|| )({dAttribute}) \b(Sub|Function|Property)\b ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     args.ShiftNextLines = args.TabLength
     Return
  End If
  If Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, $"(^\s*|| )({dAttribute}) \b(Class|Enum|Module|Structure|Namespace|Interface|Get)\b|(Set\s*\()", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     args.ShiftNextLines = args.TabLength
     Return
  End If
  ' then ...
  If Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, "\b(Then)\s*\S+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     Return
  End If
  'start of operator block
  If Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, "(^\s*|:|: |:  )(If|While|For|Do|Try|With|Using|SyncLock|Select)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     args.ShiftNextLines = args.TabLength
     Return
  End If

  'Statements else, elseif, case etc
  If Regex.IsMatch(args.LineText, "(^\s*|:|: |:  )(Else|ElseIf|Case|Catch|Finally)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
     args.Shift = -args.TabLength
     Return
  End If

  'Char _
  If args.PrevLineText.TrimEnd().EndsWith("_") Then
     args.Shift = args.TabLength
     Return
  End If
```

...e o problema persiste. **Lembrando que, aceito respostas em C#.**

Comment: Não seria identado ao invés de indenizado?

Comment: Corrigido.... obrigado

Comment: Qual é o editor que está usando? Visual Studio? Não é bastante claro na sua explicação.

Comment: Sim, é o Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: A pergunta está confusa. No inicio você diz que está modificando o projeto original, mas depois parece que está construindo um editor que usa o componente e o seu código é para configurar o componente dentro desse editor. Pode melhorar a pergunta para deixar mais claro para que serve esse componente e em que parte você está com problema?

Comment: Desculpe @Pagotti, eu descontinuei o desenvolvimento do projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer apenas corrigir a identação?

```
Ctrl+K+D
```

Caso queira uma ferramenta que faça isso em várias páginas ou até no projeto inteiro, recomendo o CodeMaid, 100% free
http://www.codemaid.net/

Existe também o `Resharper`, mas ele é pago, e utilizar ele apenas para essa finalidade é como comprar uma Ferrari para ir na Padaria.